# how to shutdown another computers by using their IPs in shell script

Tags: shell

command to shutdown to collection of servers by IP in specific time by shell script "using ssh command"

Comment: Why has to be a shell script? Do you have access to the remote system and permissions (user, or privilege) that allows you to shut it down? What services has the remote system running that would allow you to control it? SSH? telnet? other?

Comment: @Braiam I think this is a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

That command will make your computer going to shutdown.

```
$ ssh user@remote_computer sudo poweroff
```

You should notice that those two command will prompt you a password twice. To make it not ask you for a password you should copy you ssh key to your remote computer. And make poweroff command accessible by non root user.

To use a list of servers, you could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

$servers="server1 server2 server3"

for server in $servers
do
    ssh user@$server sudo poweroff
done
```

The best option to do it on specific time is scheduling the script in cron.

Comment: You might want to use `ssh user@$server sudo poweroff &` in case it is multiple servers and should run fast. This will shut down the machines in parallel instead of one after another.

Comment: I don't think `poweroff` is the best command. I don't know if it exists on all *nix variants. `shutdown` should, but I don't know about `poweroff`. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have many many servers, and you want to shut them down all in parallel, but at the same time you want to limit the number of servers that are shutdown at the same time for limiting CPU consumption for ssh encryption and for limiting the number of outgoing network connections, you could use a `Makefile` instead of a shell script.

It could look like this:

```
SERVERS:=server1 server2 server3

.PHONY: shutdown
shutdown: $(addsuffix +shutdown,$(SERVERS))

%+shutdown:
        ssh user@$* sudo poweroff
```

You could then run this using i.e. `make -j 20` to shutdown multiple in servers in parallel, limiting it to at max 20 at a time.